# Given A topology $\tau$ does it contain its subbases

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\tau$ is generated by a subbases S, is it necessarily true that $S \subset \tau$?

I am using the following definition for subbases.

A subbasis for a topology on X is a collection of subsets of X whose union equals X. The topology generated by the subbasis S is defined to be the collection $\tau$ of all unions of finite intersection of elements of S.

Comment: If $S\in\mathcal S$ then $S\in\tau$ as e.g. $S = S\cup(S\cap S)$.

Comment: Take the singleton unions/intersections.

Comment: like this $ \bigcup_{s \in S} (s \cap s \cap s ... \cap s)$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams?

Comment: No, literally $S=\cap_{\{S\}}\cup_{\{S\}} S$.

Comment: @Illustionist Why not just $(s\cap s)\cup(s\cap s)$?

Comment: yeah that works

Comment: I don't know why you add "whose union equals X". I don't think it is part of the definition. Any set of subset of $X$ is a subbase for a topology.

Comment: that how it is defined in munkres.

Comment: refresh the page and see my comment above. then check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase

Comment: @bof can you explain?

Comment: @Illustionist Suppose $s\in\mathcal S$. Then $s\cap s$ is a finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal S$, and so $(s\cap s)\cup(s\cap s)$ is a union of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal S$, so $s\in\tau.$